# Included link tags don't load css

Tags: php, html, css

I am not sure what exactly is broken and it's kinda hard to explain. My file structure looks something like this:

```
+bin
  +css
    -style.css
    -fontawesome.min.css
  +fonts
    -FontAwesome.otf
    - ...
+www
  +comp
    -header.php
    -footer.php
  -index.php
  -otherpage.php
```

Both `index.php` and `otherpage.php` [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) `header.php` and `footer.php` at the top and bottom, the content is in between.

Requesting the domain gives me the `index.php` and requesting the `otherpage.php` shows that as well as expected.

Requesting the configured `bin.domain.com/css/style.css` shows the correct css-file.

However, and this is the problem: The Link-Tag to the css-files is in the header.php and the css is not applied. Going to the Inspector shows the link-tag and following the link inside that shows the css that should apply to the page.

Now, here comes the weird thing: Going to the Style-Editor Tab in the Firefox Devtools shows the CSS from fonts.google.com as one link-tag imports a font. This is as expected but nothing else is shown so I don't even know where the error is at. Any Ideas?

Comment: The CSS has to be relative to the page being loaded, not the page being included.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I don't think you read the Question properly. The CSS is included using a "http"-request.

Comment: Like an AJAX request? Or do you have `link` tags? Or is it using an `include()`? Wait, never mind. The `link` tag `src` attribute - what is it? Is it relative to the overall page being loaded or is the path wrong?

Comment: The Main Pages use include() to add the header.php which contains the head and some other elements. Inside the head Tag is the link-tag with the href being http://bin.example.com/css/style.css.

Comment: OK - that is fairly typical. When you view the source and look at the `src` attribute of the CSS is it correct?

Comment: Yes, I wrote that in the question.

Comment: I am not able to get to chat from this location

Comment: Well, do you have any Ideas on how to solve the problem?

Comment: I have tried to replicate, but I cannot.

Comment: Can you post your code, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

The website itself was loaded via **https**. The Stylesheets and assets however where linked with **http**. I regenerated the SSL-Certificate and made the bin-subdomain a https-one. This was also said in the console in my Firefox-Browser but I didn't notice that.

This also explains why the Google-Font-Link worked while the others didn't. It was a https-request instead of a http-one.

Answer (score 0):

> Requesting the configured bin.domain.com/css/style.css shows the correct css-file.

This might not be it but you say you are using the following

```
<link href="bin.domain.com/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

What if you change it to

```
<link href="http://bin.domain.com/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```